# How does Cookie Crumbler work in Zope?

Tags: python, cookies, single-sign-on, zope

I'd like to log users from my other web app to a Zope app without having them to sign in again (Single Sign On). I wonder if it's possible to set a cookie like the way Cookie Crumbler does, and log in the user to Zope.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Plone 4, the cookie function is handled by [plone.session](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.session).

It uses a tk-auth compatible cookie, meaning you can generate these cookies if you have the shared secret. The package page contains a lot of information on how to use this for a SSO setup.